# Erase drawn lines inside the barplot

Tags: r

I would like to eliminate the lines that divide adjacent bars in a barplot in R, I've tried using "inside" but it tells me that it's not used (yet), I don't know if there's another way to do it, or if i need a package to use inside

Comment: Is `barplot(1:5, space=0)` a sufficient basic example to show your problem?

Comment: I want to delete the lines inside the bars, and obtain something like a line (like a density line), but yes we can take that as an example of the barplot

Comment: Is something like `plot(1:5, type="s", ylim=c(0,5))` sufficient?

Comment: Yes, but I would like to do it with barplot, there's an argument called "inside" but I can't use it and I don't know why, that's my problem

Comment: It hasn't been implemented in R yet - you could piece something together manually by using `?rect` to draw each piece possibly.

Comment: Oh, so that's the reason, I'll try with plot then

Comment: `barplot(1:5,space=0, border = NA)` are you trying to get something like this ?

Comment: No, I want to delete the filled of the barplot, I only want the border